# How to show error message with dynamic value in Laravel array validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am using Laravel version 5.4. I'm validating an array but it's showing an error message by default. I want to show a message for failed validations.

Here is my array input field.

```
<input readonly type="text" id="users-id" name="student_id[]" placeholder="{{ $details->batch_id }}" value="{{ $details->batch_id}}" class="form-control input-border" required>
```

I am validating the array in the controller.

```
'student_id.*'=> 'required|exists:studentinfo,batch_id|distinct|unique:student_projects,student_batchid',
```

When any validation fails it shows me an error like this.

> Given student_id.1 is not exists. Given student_id.2 is not exists.

I want to show input data instead of `student_id.1`, `student_id.2`...
Like I have inputted `111-111` in my first input field then I want to show `111-111 is not exists.`

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the error message for each rule in the `messages` method of your Form Request or directly in the `validate` method. You can use `:input` to display the user's input in the error message.

```php
$messages = [
    'student_id.*.required' => 'The student_id field is required.',
    'student_id.*.exists' => 'The student_id value :input does not exist.',
    'student_id.*.distinct' => 'The student_id value :input has already been taken.',
    'student_id.*.unique' => 'The student_id value :input has already been taken.',
];

$this->validate($request, [
    'student_id.*'=> 'required|exists:studentinfo,batch_id|distinct|unique:student_projects,student_batchid',
], $messages);
```

In this code, `:input` will be replaced with the user's input for the `student_id` field. The `validate` method will use these messages instead of the default ones for the `required`, `exists`, `distinct`, and `unique` rules.

Comment: Answer is not clear to me. Can you please help me to understand